# Java WSLD Client On The Fly

Tags: java, maven, wsdl

I have a maven project which contains a notification mechanism to customer's endpoint web service using the given wsdl location.

My question is that; do I first need to create the client using the wsdl in another project and then import the client source to my project ?

Or can I add a new maven module to my project and add the dependency of this new module to my main project so that I can easily use the methods of the wsdl. If second question's answer is "yes" then how can I do that ? should I create an initial build to be able to the java classes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a module, in your project, that represents the client's interface. You should use maven to generate the code in that module based on the wsdl. The project type should be a jar. You can then depend on that module/jar in the rest of your project. You then need to run a maven install, at least once, to generate the classes and build a jar for your repo.

[The Apache CXF project has a maven plugin.](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html)